# Flutter app crash without error in Debug Console

Tags: flutter, dart

I'm trying to make an POS(point of sale) app in Flutter.

Everytime I try to work on the app (adding new orders etc..) the app freezes for 2 minutes then come back to work with a status in Debug Console as `Lost connection to device` with no errors.

This happend after the update to `Flutter 3.0.0`.

I have a simple code , nothing suspicious. a button that will add an item to a list.

Comment: can you provide the error screenshot?

Comment: there is no error. Simply the app crashes and not responding.

Comment: Adding new orders means? do you post anything to API or store it in the local DB?

Comment: if you don't want Flutter 3.0.0 you can downgrade to the previous known stable version know.